# How to add reference of class library project in asp net core 1.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created asp net core project.
How can I add a class library in the project and where to add the reference to it.

Here is a glimpse of the project in the screenshot attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcArj.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your class library reference like this-

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    "dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrary1": {
        "target": "project"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Or you could right click on the src folder and select Add -> Existing Project like all other Visual Studio versions.

Comment: If the class library project has DI through Castle.Windsor, how to resolve that dependency? I can reference my class library project, but dependencies are not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

By selecting 'Add project reference' from the context menu when right-clicking on Dependencies inside your project in visual studio, you can add references. The reference manager will appear, and you can select a different project or library from there.